# Understanding Gulp sass compilation

Tags: node.js, compilation, sass, npm, gulp

I have a gulpfile.js with some tasks to compile client side coffeescript and my styles which are in sass. The coffeescript is compiling correctly, but sass is not.

Here is my gulpfile.js -

```
var gulp   = require('gulp'),
    util   = require('gulp-util'),
    sass   = require('gulp-sass'),
    coffee = require('gulp-coffee');

var paths = {
    scripts: {
        src:  'src/coffee/**/*.coffee',
        dest: 'public/javascripts'
    },
    styles: {
        src:  'src/*.sass',
        dest: 'public/stylesheets'
    }
};

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.scripts.src)
        .pipe(coffee())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dest));
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
   return gulp.src(paths.styles.src)
       .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
       .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch(paths.scripts.src, ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, ['styles']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'watch']);
```

It's got to be in my 'watch' task, but what is it missing?

*** EDIT ***

Here is the output I am getting -

```
[gulp] Using file exampledir/gulpfile.js
[gulp] Working directory changed to exampledir/examplesite
[gulp] Running 'scripts'...
[gulp] Running 'watch'...
[gulp] Finished 'watch' in 14 ms
[gulp] Finished 'scripts' in 106 ms
[gulp] Running 'default'...
[gulp] Finished 'default' in 10 μs
```

Comment: is the path  `/src/*.sass` correct?

Comment: No, thank you for pointing that out, it should just be `src/*.sass`. But that, unfortunately, isn't solving the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you forgot the `.src` oth your `gulp.src(path.styles)`.

It bet it will work better :)

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
   return gulp.src(paths.styles.src)
     .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
     .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
});
```

*** EDIT ***

Other point: the default task does not depends on the saas task. That's why it's not executed.

```
gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'sass', 'watch']);
```

will fix it.

Otherwise, watch just wait for one of your style files to be modified before compiling it.
It does not trigger the compilation when starting.

*** EDIT v2 ***

If you which to compile both `.scss` and `.sass` extension, just adapt your path.styles.src variable.

```
paths = {
    ...
    styles: {
       src:  ['src/*.scss', 'src/*.sass']
    ...
```

Should work. Unless it's the way [vinyl-fs](https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl-fs) seems to work.

*** EDIT v3 ***

Damn.
The watch on styles folder isn't correct. It triggers a undeinfed `styles` task.
try changing it to `sass` task.

```
gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, ['sass']);
```

Comment: While you are very true with your insight (thank you!) it did not remedy the situation. I edit my _index.sass file, and gulp does not recognize it while running the watch task. Thank you for the gulp.src point though!

Comment: It added sass to the output, but did not compile my sass. Is this module not capable of compiling sass NOT scss?

Comment: Yes it does. .scss and .sass extensions are both supporte by sass compiler. But in your src variable, you said '*.sass'. Therefore it totally ignore .scss files. I'll post another edit :)

Comment: That is correct though, I don't want scss. All my files are in indented sass.

Comment: Same here. I would like to use the indented SASS syntax.

Answer (score 0):

After spend a long time trying to use the gulp-sass to compile my .sass files I decided to use the compass plugin instead. Works like a charm:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/sass/' + '**/*.sass')
    .pipe($plugin.plumber())
    .pipe($plugin.compass({
      css:   './public/css',
      sass:  './src/sass/'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'));
});
```

Comment: Agreed, this is great for projects using compass.